# How to start server in Sparkjava?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spark-java

The docs say how to stop the server: `stop()` and to visit localhost after running it but doesn't specify how to start it. I have everything else set up and no errors when I run `mvn install`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `mvn install` does is only build your jar.

To run it just do

```
java -jar <your jar name>
```

Answer (score 1):

The server is started during the first route declaration.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
    }
}
```

The static method *get* invokes a singleton that will ignite the server. Subsequent calls to that api (*get*, *post*, *put*, etc.) will only register the routes, because the server is already started.

Since [Sparkjava 2.5](http://sparkjava.com/news.html#spark25released), it is possible to explicitly start not only one, but multiple services through the *spark.Service.ignite()* api.